# Flickr integration-Search result doesn't display any image

Tags: android, flickr

I am trying to integrate flickr in my project and display images on searching.But on searching it doesn't display any image.I have used this tutorial  http://michalu.eu/wordpress/android-flickr-api-tutorial/ ..I am unable to figure out where i have gone wrong..

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public final String LAST_IMAGE = "lastImage";
        public UIHandler uihandler;
        public ImageAdapter imgAdapter;
        private ArrayList<ImageContener> imageList;

        // UI
        private Button downloadPhotos;
        private Gallery gallery;
        private ImageView imgView;
        private EditText editText;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Init UI Handler
            uihandler = new UIHandler();

            downloadPhotos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
            imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            // Click on thumbnail
            gallery.setOnItemClickListener(onThumbClickListener);
            // Click on search
            downloadPhotos.setOnClickListener(onSearchButtonListener);

            // Get prevoiusly downloaded list after orientation change
            imageList = (ArrayList<ImageContener>) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            if (imageList != null) {
                imgAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), imageList);
                ArrayList<ImageContener> ic = imgAdapter.getImageContener();
                gallery.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
                imgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                int lastImage = -1;
                if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(LAST_IMAGE)) {
                    lastImage = savedInstanceState.getInt(LAST_IMAGE);
                }
                if (lastImage >= 0 && ic.size() >= lastImage) {
                    gallery.setSelection(lastImage);
                    Bitmap photo = ic.get(lastImage).getPhoto();
                    if (photo == null)
                        new GetLargePhotoThread(ic.get(lastImage), uihandler).start();
                    else
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(ic.get(lastImage).photo);
                }
            }

        }

        /**
         * Saving information about images
         */
        @Override
        public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
            if (imgAdapter != null)
                return this.imgAdapter.getImageContener();
            else
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            // Saving index of selected item in Gallery
            outState.putInt(LAST_IMAGE, gallery.getSelectedItemPosition());
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        }

        /**
         * 
         * @author michalu
         * 
         *         Downloading a larger photo using Thread
         */
        public class GetLargePhotoThread extends Thread {
            ImageContener ic;
            UIHandler uih;

            public GetLargePhotoThread(ImageContener ic, UIHandler uih) {
                this.ic = ic;
                this.uih = uih;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (ic.getPhoto() == null) {
                    ic.setPhoto(FlickrManager.getImage(ic));
                }
                Bitmap bmp = ic.getPhoto();
                if (ic.getPhoto() != null) {
                    Message msg = Message.obtain(uih, UIHandler.ID_SHOW_IMAGE);
                    msg.obj = bmp;
                    uih.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Runnable to get metadata from Flickr API
         */
        Runnable getMetadata = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String tag = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (tag != null && tag.length() >= 3)
                    FlickrManager.searchImagesByTag(uihandler, getApplicationContext(), tag);
            }
        };

        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context mContext;
            private int defaultItemBackground;
            private ArrayList<ImageContener> imageContener;

            public ArrayList<ImageContener> getImageContener() {
                return imageContener;
            }

            public void setImageContener(ArrayList<ImageContener> imageContener) {
                this.imageContener = imageContener;
            }

            public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ImageContener> imageContener) {
                mContext = c;
                this.imageContener = imageContener;
                TypedArray styleAttrs = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.PicGallery);
                styleAttrs.getResourceId(R.styleable.PicGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
                defaultItemBackground = styleAttrs.getResourceId(R.styleable.PicGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
                styleAttrs.recycle();
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return imageContener.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
                if (imageContener.get(position).thumb != null) {
                    i.setImageBitmap(imageContener.get(position).thumb);
                    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(75, 75));
                    i.setBackgroundResource(defaultItemBackground);
                } else
                    i.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.black));
                return i;
            }

        }

        /**
         * 
         * @author michalu
         * 
         *         UI Handler to handle messages from threads
         */
        class UIHandler extends Handler {
            public static final int ID_METADATA_DOWNLOADED = 0;
            public static final int ID_SHOW_IMAGE = 1;
            public static final int ID_UPDATE_ADAPTER = 2;

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case ID_METADATA_DOWNLOADED:
                    // Set of information required to download thumbnails is
                    // available now
                    if (msg.obj != null) {
                        imageList = (ArrayList<ImageContener>) msg.obj;
                        imgAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), imageList);
                        gallery.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
                        for (int i = 0; i < imgAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                            new GetThumbnailsThread(uihandler, imgAdapter.getImageContener().get(i)).start();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case ID_SHOW_IMAGE:
                    // Display large image
                    if (msg.obj != null) {
                        imgView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) msg.obj);
                        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    break;
                case ID_UPDATE_ADAPTER:
                    // Update adapter with thumnails
                    imgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                }
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }

        OnItemClickListener onThumbClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                // Get large image of selected thumnail
                new GetLargePhotoThread(imageList.get(position), uihandler).start();
            }
        };

        /**
         * to get metadata from Flickr API
         */
        OnClickListener onSearchButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (gallery.getAdapter() != null) {
                    imgAdapter.imageContener = new ArrayList<ImageContener>();
                    gallery.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
                    imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                new Thread(getMetadata).start();
            }
        };

    }
```

FlickrManager.java

```
public class FlickrManager {

    // String to create Flickr API urls
    private static final String FLICKR_BASE_URL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=";
    private static final String FLICKR_PHOTOS_SEARCH_STRING = "flickr.photos.search";
    private static final String FLICKR_GET_SIZES_STRING = "flickr.photos.getSizes";
    private static final int FLICKR_PHOTOS_SEARCH_ID = 1;
    private static final int FLICKR_GET_SIZES_ID = 2;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_PHOTOS = 20;

    //You can set here your API_KEY
    private static final String APIKEY_SEARCH_STRING = "&api_key=31c97c8908514f10f10b64b1bac83ec9";

    private static final String TAGS_STRING = "&tags=";
    private static final String PHOTO_ID_STRING = "&photo_id=";
    private static final String FORMAT_STRING = "&format=json";
    public static final int PHOTO_THUMB = 111;
    public static final int PHOTO_LARGE = 222;

    public static UIHandler uihandler;

    private static String createURL(int methodId, String parameter) {
        String method_type = "";
        String url = null;
        switch (methodId) {
        case FLICKR_PHOTOS_SEARCH_ID:
            method_type = FLICKR_PHOTOS_SEARCH_STRING;
            url = FLICKR_BASE_URL + method_type + APIKEY_SEARCH_STRING + TAGS_STRING + parameter + FORMAT_STRING + "&per_page="+NUMBER_OF_PHOTOS+"&media=photos";
            break;
        case FLICKR_GET_SIZES_ID:
            method_type = FLICKR_GET_SIZES_STRING;
            url = FLICKR_BASE_URL + method_type + PHOTO_ID_STRING + parameter + APIKEY_SEARCH_STRING + FORMAT_STRING;
            break;
        }
        return url;
    }

    // http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg
    public static void getImageURLS(ImageContener imgCon) {
        String url = createURL(FLICKR_GET_SIZES_ID, imgCon.id);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = URLConnector.readBytes(url);
        String json = baos.toString();
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json.replace("jsonFlickrApi(", "").replace(")", ""));
            JSONObject sizes = root.getJSONObject("sizes");
            JSONArray size = sizes.getJSONArray("size");
            for (int i = 0; i < size.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject image = size.getJSONObject(i);
                if (image.getString("label").equals("Square")) {
                    imgCon.setThumbURL(image.getString("source"));
                } else if (image.getString("label").equals("Medium")) {
                    imgCon.setLargeURL(image.getString("source"));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap getImage(ImageContener imgCon) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(imgCon.largeURL);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("FlickrManager", e.getMessage());
        }
        return bm;
    }

    public static void getThumbnails(ArrayList<ImageContener> imgCon, UIHandler uih) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imgCon.size(); i++)
            new GetThumbnailsThread(uih, imgCon.get(i)).start();
    }

    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(ImageContener imgCon) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(imgCon.thumbURL);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("FlickrManager", e.getMessage());
        }
        return bm;
    }

    public static class GetThumbnailsThread extends Thread {
        UIHandler uih;
        ImageContener imgContener;

        public GetThumbnailsThread(UIHandler uih, ImageContener imgCon) {
            this.uih = uih;
            this.imgContener = imgCon;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            imgContener.thumb = getThumbnail(imgContener);
            if (imgContener.thumb != null) {
                Message msg = Message.obtain(uih, UIHandler.ID_UPDATE_ADAPTER);
                uih.sendMessage(msg);

            }
        }

    }

    public static ArrayList<ImageContener> searchImagesByTag(UIHandler uih, Context ctx, String tag) {
        uihandler = uih;
        String url = createURL(FLICKR_PHOTOS_SEARCH_ID, tag);
        ArrayList<ImageContener> tmp = new ArrayList<ImageContener>();
        String jsonString = null;
        try {
            if (URLConnector.isOnline(ctx)) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = URLConnector.readBytes(url);
                jsonString = baos.toString();
            }
            try {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonString.replace("jsonFlickrApi(", "").replace(")", ""));
                JSONObject photos = root.getJSONObject("photos");
                JSONArray imageJSONArray = photos.getJSONArray("photo");
                for (int i = 0; i < imageJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject item = imageJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ImageContener imgCon = new ImageContener(item.getString("id"), item.getString("owner"), item.getString("secret"), item.getString("server"),
                            item.getString("farm"));
                    imgCon.position = i;
                    tmp.add(imgCon);
                }
                Message msg = Message.obtain(uih, UIHandler.ID_METADATA_DOWNLOADED);
                msg.obj = tmp;
                uih.sendMessage(msg);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException nue) {
            nue.printStackTrace();
        }

        return tmp;
    }

}
```

URLConnector.java

```
public class URLConnector {

    private static int CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;
    private static int READ_TIMEOUT_MS = 15000;
    public static boolean isOnline(Context ctx) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Read all bytes from urlS
     * 
     * @param urlS
     * @return ByteArrayOutputStream with content or null
     */
    public static ByteArrayOutputStream readBytes(String urlS) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {
            // HTTP connection reuse which was buggy pre-froyo
            if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
                System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            }
            URL url = new URL(urlS);
            Log.i("URL", url.toString());
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int response = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS);
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_MS);
                is = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

                int size = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

                baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    if (read > 0) {
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        buffer = new byte[size];
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                try {
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return baos;
    }
}
```

ImageContener.java

```
public class ImageContener implements IThumb {
    String id;
    int position;
    String thumbURL;
    Bitmap thumb;
    Bitmap photo;
    String largeURL;
    String owner;
    String secret;
    String server;
    String farm;

    public ImageContener(String id, String thumbURL, String largeURL, String owner, String secret, String server, String farm) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.secret = secret;
        this.server = server;
        this.farm = farm;
    }

    public ImageContener(String id, String owner, String secret, String server, String farm) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.secret = secret;
        this.server = server;
        this.farm = farm;
        setThumbURL(createPhotoURL(FlickrManager.PHOTO_THUMB, this));
        setLargeURL(createPhotoURL(FlickrManager.PHOTO_LARGE, this));
    }

    public String getThumbURL() {
        return thumbURL;
    }

    public void setThumbURL(String thumbURL) {
        this.thumbURL = thumbURL;
        onSaveThumbURL(FlickrManager.uihandler, this);
    }

    public String getLargeURL() {
        return largeURL;
    }

    public void setLargeURL(String largeURL) {
        this.largeURL = largeURL;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ImageContener [id=" + id + ", thumbURL=" + thumbURL + ", largeURL=" + largeURL + ", owner=" + owner + ", secret=" + secret + ", server=" + server + ", farm="
                + farm + "]";
    }

    private String createPhotoURL(int photoType, ImageContener imgCon) {
        String tmp = null;
        tmp = "http://farm" + imgCon.farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + imgCon.server + "/" + imgCon.id + "_" + imgCon.secret;// +".jpg";
        switch (photoType) {
        case FlickrManager.PHOTO_THUMB:
            tmp += "_t";
            break;
        case FlickrManager.PHOTO_LARGE:
            tmp += "_z";
            break;

        }
        tmp += ".jpg";
        return tmp;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Bitmap getThumb() {
        return thumb;
    }

    public void setThumb(Bitmap thumb) {
        this.thumb = thumb;
    }

    public Bitmap getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(Bitmap photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    public String getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    public void setServer(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public String getFarm() {
        return farm;
    }

    public void setFarm(String farm) {
        this.farm = farm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveThumbURL(UIHandler uih, ImageContener ic) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new GetThumbnailsThread(uih, ic).start();
    }
}
```

IThumb.java

```
public interface IThumb {
    public void onSaveThumbURL(UIHandler uih, ImageContener ic);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method="; instead of "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=" then it will work.